# 'Jump Url' in solr search results

Tags: solr, lucene

my company uses an external company to provide their search needs (SLI) I have implemented Solr instead as it is free and frankly superior. However SLI provide a feature where if you search for special keywords like "help" or "contact" the response from SLI will not include the content and instead only a few nodes similar to

```
<response>
    <merch><jumpurl>http://somedomain.com/somejumpurl</jumpurl></merch>
</response>
```

Any ideas how I can provide this feature with Solr?

Comment: are those special words predefined in a config file or something?

Comment: yes they could be I guess, in SLI you enter these words in their console.

Comment: Are you looking for something like: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent ?

Comment: Yes I think that's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is then a type of "sponsored search".
Something similar to that in Solr can be achieved with the [QueryElevationComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent).

You need to configure it in your solrconfig.xml, then make a dedicated field to use it and then create an external xml file with your special words and rules you want to apply, for example:

```
<elevate>

  <query text="AAA">
   <doc id="A" />
   <doc id="B" />
  </query>

  <query text="ipod">
    <doc id="A" />

        <!-- you can optionally exclude documents from a query result -->
    <doc id="B" exclude="true" />
  </query>

</elevate>
```

And then use it in this way:

```
http://host/solr/elevate?q=YYYY&debugQuery=true&enableElevation=true
```

If you want to return only the results specified in the elevation file, add exclusive=true to the URL:

```
http://host/solr/elevate?q=YYYY&debugQuery=true&exclusive=true
```